# PHP - How to get all Array Values of an n deep miltidimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am trying to get all array values of an multidimentional array, but the thing is array can be 1 levels deep or 2, 3 or 4 , i.e. n levels deep.

here are some random e.g. of array contents.

e.g.1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => name1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => name2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => name3
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => name4
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => name4
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => name5
        )
)
```

e.g.2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name0
            [1] => name1
            [2] => name2
            [3] => name3
            [4] => name4
            [5] => name5
        )
)
```

I want all values to be in new array.
So  far i have tried something like this.

looping for n times using `foreach` loop, its working fine for now, but i would like to know if its programmatically correct or is there any other way which is faster or better than this one.

PHP CODE.

```
<?php
$out_final_array = array ();
function foreach_values_endless($array){
global $out_final_array;
    /* if its array */
    if(is_array($array)){
        /*run foreach loop to find more sub arrays */
        foreach ($array as $value){
            /* if value is an array send to own custom function */
            if(is_array($value)){
                $out_final_array[] = foreach_values_endless(array_values($value));
            }else{
            /* value is not an array*/
                $out_final_array[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }else{
        /* value is not array */
        $out_final_array[] = $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes a recursive function as you've built is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to flatten it, another way would be to use SPL [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) and [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$new_data = array();
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));
foreach($it as $v) {
    $new_data[] = $v;
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2wEwQy)

Sidenote: No need for that `global` just have it `return` the values:

```
function foreach_values_endless($array){
    $data = array();

    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $data = array_merge($data, foreach_values_endless($v));
        } else {
            $data[] = $v;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ox65Vf)

Comment: if i dont use global, wont the second call to foreach_values_endless($v) , make $data  array null ? and restart from 0

Comment: @AMB no, at that point, you're still recursively getting depth, haven't you tried it?

Comment: yes, i have tried it, and its working as expected. but ihad a doubt.

Comment: okie, just noticed that we are calling our custom function inside array_merge, so the returned array from function gets merged in our original array, at each level down. thanks

Comment: @AMB yes thats it, it gets merged onto it

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_walk_recursuve()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
$final = array();

array_walk_recursive($input, function($item, $key) use (&$final){
   $final[0][] = $item;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Just loop through all of your values with [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), like this:

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k)use(&$result){
    $result[] = $v;
});

print_r($result);
```