# How to retrieve a deep subarray using key from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have the below array and trying to get the value of the key named 'Summary' from `$array` variable.

```
["Rows"]=>
array(1) {
  ["Row"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Rows"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["Row"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(1) {
            ["Rows"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["Row"]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["Summary"]=>
                  array(1) {
                    ["ColData"]=>
                    array(2) {
                      [0]=>
                      array(1) {
                        ["value"]=>
                        string(19) "Some Value"
                      }
                      [1]=>
                      array(1) {
                        ["value"]=>
                        string(7) "2001.00"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried following,

```
array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['Summary'];}, $array);
```

But didn't get success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `array_map` will not go deeper than first level, that's all

Comment: @u_mulder Edited the question. Please help.

Comment: i would suggest using `array_walk_recursive`, i'd give you a snippet if i had time but check out [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997923/3219054)

Comment: @scosu `array_walk_recursive()` will only iterate the "leaf-nodes" of the array, it will not work for this case.

Comment: @mickmackusa There may be dynamic rows before finding Summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three options:

([Demo of first two methods](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7693107bb759202f62f21804eb94f7a561e50c6f))

You can use a simple recursion function like this:

Code #1:

```
function recursive($array){
    if(key($array)!=='Summary'){
        return recursive(current($array));
    }
    return current($array);
} 
var_export(recursive($array));
```

Or you can literally access the desired subarray without using any function calls.  You just need to name every key (assuming the structure is static).

Code #2:

```
$array=[
    'Rows'=>[
        'Row'=>[
            [
                'Rows'=>[
                    'Row'=>[
                        [
                            'Rows'=>[
                                'Row'=>[
                                    [
                                        'Summary'=>[
                                            'ColData'=>[
                                                ['value'=>'Some Value'],
                                                ['value'=>'2001.00']
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
var_export($array['Rows']['Row'][0]['Rows']['Row'][0]['Rows']['Row'][0]['Summary']);
```

To leverage assumptions about array structure, you can implement a recursive process that "jumps" levels per iteration:

Code #3:

```
function recursive_jumper($array){
    if(key($array)!=='Summary'){
        return recursive_jumper($array['Rows']['Row'][0]);
    }
    return current($array);
} 
var_export(recursive_jumper($array));
```

Output (from any of the above methods):

```
array (
  'ColData' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'Some Value',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'value' => '2001.00',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function searchArray($needle, $haystack, &$matched = null)
{
    if (is_array($haystack) && count($haystack) > 0) {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
            if ((string)$key === (string)$needle) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $matched = $value;
                } else {
                    $matched[] = $value;
                }
            } else {
                if (is_array($value) && count($value) > 0) {
                    self::searchArray($needle, $value, $matched);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    return true;
} 
searchArray('Summary', $yourArray, $found);
var_dump($found);
```